# Update IP configuration /etc/network/interfaces from web page

Tags: network-programming, raspbian

We are creating an opensource web appliance based on Raspberry Pi /Raspbian / LAMP and would like users to be able to configure the Raspbian IP settings from a configuration web page. (so some fields on a page to make users choose between DHCP / Fixed IP, subnet mask and gateway, which is then stored in /etc/network/interfaces.

I would be very grateful if anyone could point me to existing HTML/PHP/js/... code which I can incorporate into the setup of our application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is exactly what you are looking for, but if you are making your appliance web-only UI (instead of a desktop-login based device), you might want to look into using OpenWRT instead of the regular desktop OS, and make a few modifications to the web front end suit your needs:

http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/raspberry_pi

And for setting LAMP on top of OpenWRT:

http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/lamp

Comment: Jorge, thanks for your response. I am sorry I was not clear. 
The raspberry pi appliance we are making is a website to control home automation (lights-on/off etc.). The goal is that non-technical electricians can use our disk-image, put it on an SD-card, boot up the pi and start using it. I would like to have a simple web interface that updates /etc/network/interfaces. Something that would look like this.

http://www.tp-link.com/resources/images/faq/20114793950364.jpg

Which we could incorporate into the browser-based config wizard for the web application.

Comment: The appliance that you mention sounds interesting. Now back to the topic. If installing a Web-UI based OS distribution for your appliance, such as OpenWRT, is an overkill for what you need, and the only thing that you need is a back-end that responds to a form similar to the one that you attachen in the image, the only thing that I can think about would be making my own PHP script to handle the form's input. It should not be such a big task to get it done. I am not aware of any pre-packaged solutions other than what I mentioned before and home-brewing your own. Sorry.